# Loading image without interrupting user

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, tabview, loading-image

How to add loading "tag" on particular tab. ?

There is a main screen, where you see many tabs and you can make some "moves" in a main panel.

On a left side of main screen, there is several tabs, one of the tabs is `Messages`
which has `<p:poll>` and is beeing refreshed every 60 seconds.. During refresh, user get a loading "Circle" in a center of screen and all usage is blocked for ~3-2 seconds, which is very annoying.

So what I want to make, is that `Messages` refresh would not interrupt user and would be indicated only by small loading "circle" or any other loading atribute on its tab.

Comment: I think everybody would like to get private support from him...

Comment: Have the `<p:poll>` update only the necessary portion (`<p:poll process="@this" update="componentsToBeUpdated" .../>`).

Comment: @Tiny did, but seems no difference, still when I am in messages scope, screen freezes and I get loading circle during refresh

Comment: If you have a `<p:ajaxStatus>` in your page or template, maybe you should remove it if you don't need it.